# Symfony2 Rest api,metodo PUT,request a nulo con multipart/form-data

Tags: api, rest, symfony2

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/9226

Por lo que he podido ver en el post que dejo ahi existe un bug en PHP que hace que la request llegue a nulo con este tipo de content type,¿alguien tiene una solución para pasar ficheros a un servicio rest con el método put?.Yo lo he solucionado usando post,pero eso mata la especificación de una API REST que dice que la edición debe ser a traves del método PUT.

la llamada la hago con angular de esta manera :

```
...
var noticiasForm = new FormData(document.getElementById("noticiasForm"));
                        var config = {
                            headers : {
                                   'Content-Type': undefined
                               },
                            transformRequest: angular.identity
                        };

                        global = $http.put(path+'noticias/'+noticia.id, noticiasForm, config);
                        return global;
```

y en el controlador hago esto :

```
/**
 * Edita una noticia
 * Put action
 * @var Request $request
 * @var Noticias $noticia
 * @return View|array
 *
 * @View()
 * @Put("/noticias/{id}")
 */
 public function editNoticiaAction(Request $request, $id)
 {

    $errores = array();

    $d1 = file_get_contents("php://input");

    $foto = $request->files->get('foto_noti');
    $titulo = $request->request->get('titulo_noti');
    $texto = $request->request->get('texto_noti');
    $id_usu = $request->request->get('id_usuario');
}
```

Ninguno de los datos que trato de obtener en la request llega relleno,
Con el método POST funciona todo bien.

Por último,una reflexión,estamos pensando en pasarnos a Java para estas cosas,los servicios REST y PHP,junto con symfony no parecen estar muy en lo suyo,según dicen en ese hilo,el bug es de 2011 y todavía sigue vivo. Me parece un serio desastre esto,por ello sopesamos la posibilidad de cambiar a Java toda la API REST. ¿Alguna recomendación?¿pensais lo mismo que yo?

Comment: es un bug relacionado a php en sí. Ya han subido soluciones a lo que planteas mas no han sido aprovadas en el core, así que tocará hacer las modificaciones pertinentes, compilar php y usar ésta versión modificada.

Comment: tendré que estudiar esas soluciones,aunque lo que he visto no lo entiendo muy bien,por eso he usado post,de momento me sirve pero no es lo que me gustaría.Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.